# how to calculate number of days between today and given date and code for getTime()?

Tags: javascript, extjs

I want to calculate number of days between today and a given date and check whether how many days remaining until today or how many days past from today.

```
var today = new Date();
var date_to_reply = new Date('2012-10-15');
var timeinmilisec = today.getTime() - date_to_reply.getTime();
console.log( Math.floor(timeinmilisec / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)) );
```

this gives me **5** as answer but how should i get **(-5)** since the date_to_reply is 5days past from today?

is this the correct way to calculate any given date?

Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the value to be negative (indicating `date_to_reply` is in the past) you should subtract the past date from the current: `date_to_reply.getTime() - today.getTime()`.

Check [this link](http://www.htmlgoodies.com/html5/javascript/calculating-the-difference-between-two-dates-in-javascript.html#fbid=-d7WptXGPzn) for ways to calculate more diffentiated results.

Answer (score 9):

What you are doing is correct: You want to calculate the **difference** (as number of days) between two dates. A difference can't be smaller than zero.

Although your `date_to_reply` is already in the past, theres still a 5 day difference.

So, everythings fine - it's the correct way.

EDIT:
If you want a negative value as result, try this:

```
var today = new Date();
var date_to_reply = new Date('2012-10-15');
var timeinmilisec = date_to_reply.getTime() - today.getTime();
console.log( Math.ceil(timeinmilisec / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)) );
```

Remember you need to `Math.ceil` the final result instead of rounding it down with `Math.floor()`.

Answer (score 1):

If you swap the order of the dates, you'll get the negative number you want.

Better yet you could write a function that does this.

It could subtract the first parameter from the second.

The second parameter could default to today.

```
function diffDates(dateOne, dateTwo) {
    if (typeof dateTwo === 'undefined') {
        dateTwo = new Date();
    }
    return dateOne.getTime() - dateTwo.getTime();
}
```

It would be better to have the function operate on numbers rather than dates.

That would be more flexible, but I'm typing on an iPad right now!

Answer (score 0):

Its obvious because today's date is greater than the previous. So either you need to make it negative on your own or use this

```
var timeinmilisec = date_to_reply.getTime()-today.getTime();
```